# Linq Select two colums of different types

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following Linq query:

```
var dis = productsWhole
          .SelectMany(p => p.CustomerPricing).ToList();
```

this allows foreach access to each item from the productsWhole.CustomerPricing List.

the productsWhole ienumerable also contains a String field ProductCode is there a way of combining both without using select new anonymous types ?

Comment: You should use Joins and project the results you want. See here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: What exact output do you want?

Comment: preferably in the foreach iteration of var dis the list fields, as existing and the productCode field.

Comment: The following would give you both items `.SelectMany(p => Tuple.Create(p.CustomerPricing, p.ProductCode)` without an anonymous type but I'm still unclear as to what you're expecting the output to be.

Comment: try suggestion from test, this falls over with, type argument errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of projecting to a `Tuple` as @test suggested is to use the [SelectMany overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx) that supports additional `resultSelector` like this

```
var dis = productsWhole
    .SelectMany(p => p.CustomerPricing, (p, cp) => Tuple.Create(p.ProductCode, cp))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the anonymous type part you are concerned about (I presume you want to return this from a method or something like that), either project to a known type (such as Tuple as test suggested) or to a pre-defined type (such as your own struct or class), e.g.:

```
internal class ProductProjection
{
  internal CustomerPricing CustomerPricing { get; set; }
  internal string ProductCode { get; set; }
}
```

then do:

```
var dis = productsWhole
          .SelectMany(p => new ProductProjection { CustomerPricing = p.CustomerPricing, ProductCode = p.ProductCode }).ToList();
```

`dis` will then be a `List<ProductProjection>`